# Pattern match all the HTTP errors

Tags: pattern-matching, elm

I have an update function such as:

```
update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update msg model =
    case msg of 
        NewImages (Ok images) ->
          ({model|images = images}, Cmd.none)

        NewImages (Err error) ->
          myFunction model

        NewUsers (Ok users) ->
          ({model|users = users}, Cmd.none)

        NewUsers (Err error) ->
          myFunction model

        [...]
```

and a function `myFunction` that I would like to call every time I get an HTTP.Error.

Apparently, `_` cannot be used to match only the beginning of a pattern like in

```
update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update msg model =
    case msg of 
        NewImages (Ok images) ->
          ({model|images = images}, Cmd.none)

        NewUsers (Ok users) ->
          ({model|users = users}, Cmd.none)

        _ (Err error) ->
          myFunction model

        [...]
```

So, what would be the proper way to match all Http.Error in my update function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how to match all `Http.Error`s in update function, but you can map all `Http.Error`s to a dedicated message.

```
type Msg
    = NewImages (List String)
    | ...
    | HttpError Http.Error

send : (a -> Msg) -> Request Http.Error a -> Cmd Msg
send tagger request =
    let
        makeMsg result =
            case result of
                Ok a ->
                    tagger a

                Err error ->
                    HttpError error
    in
        Http.send makeMsg request

-- and make an HTTP request like:
send NewImages request
```

Then you can match all your HTTP errors.

```
update msg model =
    case msg of
        NewImages images ->
            ({ model | images = images }, Cmd.none)

        ...

        HttpError error ->
            myFunction error
```